# Actualizar dados (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou com um problema relacionado com dados externos no excel este é um exemplo do que tenho feito:

`Index` (Livro) `Painel` (folha) - Introduzo dados no painel que serão enviados para outro livro (contagem) folha (soma) e receberá os dados vindos da mesma.

`Contagem`(livro) `Soma` (folha) - faz o calculo e envia o resultado para Livro (`index`) folha (`painel`).

A questão que eu tenho é que sempre que quero actualizar estes dados tenho que ter ambos os livros de `excel` abertos e queria saber se existe alguma forma de o fazer com apenas o livro (`index`) aberto e o livro (`contagem`) fechado?

Comment: Acredito que não, pois o excel só atualiza dados em planilhas abertas, infelizmente...Dá para você colocar uma macro na planilha index que ao ser atualizada, abre a outra planilha, atualiza ela e depois a fecha, isso é possível, com VBA, dê uma pesquisada ai.

Comment: Obrigado pela info, fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei este forum
"http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/137036-resolvido-abrir-arquivo-excel-e-salvar/"

No entanto fiz o que estava la e não deu resultado apenas consigo fazer o mesmo que antes abrir o ficheiro. O meu objectivo seria fazer isso de forma transparente sem que o utilizador se percebesse.

Comment: isso é meio que "impossível", pois o excel vai abrir a planilha e o utilizador verá que a mesma esta sendo atualizada, até porque a planilha vai dar uma travada básica (coisas de excel mesmo).

Comment: A sua pergunta não está tão clara. Vc tem um código VBA que atualiza algo em uma planilha e quer fazer isso em uma planilha (arquivo) fechado? É isso? Edite e deixe mais claro, se possível até exibindo o trecho de código em que você faz a tal atualização dos dados.